# Ratio of area between similar triangles

Tags: triangles, area, ratio

[image: question2]

This question has nearly no information and I've been stuck on this for quite some time. I tried drawing the median from A thru G but the 1x to 2x ratio didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Draw the line $AG$, and suppose it meets $BC$ at the point $M$. Then by standard properties of the centroid, we have $AG=2GM$. This observation (which you made) *is* useful.

Note that the area of $\triangle DFE$ is the same as the area of $\triangle DME$, and that the area of $\triangle ADE$ is four-ninths of the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: And the answer is 9/2 ? What use is the area ratio between ADE and ABC ??

Comment: What use? It gives the answer.

Comment: If my answer isn't correct could you walk me through it because i don't see how knowing the area ratio between ADE and ABC gets me the area ratio between ABC and DFE

Comment: The area of $ADE$ is twice the area of $DFE$ (same base, $2$ to $1$ ratio of heights). And the area of $ADE$ is $(2/3)^2$ of the area of $ABC$. That gives required ratio is $9/2$.